# Having trouble to make custom edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

i want to make custom edit text like [this](http://jubayer.eu5.org/images/message_box.JPG)

I searched google fot it but get any solution to my desire.
 So please give me some advise how to do it or give a documentation link  that will help me.
Thanks in advance.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends EditText.  Override the onDraw method to draw it however you want.

Comment: can you give some sample example of this @ Gabe Sechan